# Convert XML to object in PHP a update values of some node and again convert object to XML?

Tags: php, xml

I am dealing with multiple APIs. Please find some steps.
**Step1**  I have got the first API's result as below. 
    **Let's say I have got the following response.**

```
     $xml = '<soap:Envelope
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <Response
          xmlns="http://schemas.martin-group.com/test">
          <Result>
            <![CDATA[
            <AccountInfo><CusAccount Action="Add" AccountID="2046369" DesiredCycleID="0" Name="" 
             Corporation="" Cycle=""><AccountType><CusAccountType AccountTypeID="100001" Version="1" 
             AccountTypeCode="BUS " AccountType="Business" MonthlyBillingMethod="P" /></AccountType> 
             <InvoiceFormat><ICInvoiceFormat InvoiceFormatID="1" UserID="10490655" 
             AddressAdjustmentY="0" AddressWidth="3500"/></InvoiceFormat></CusAccount> 
             </AccountInfo>]]>
         </Result>
       </Response>
    </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>';
```

**Step2** I have converted XML to XML Object.

```
     $soap = simplexml_load_string($xml);
     $soap->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
     $object = $soap->xpath('//soap:Envelope/soap:Body')[0]->Response;
     $cdata = $object->Result;
     $cdata_as_xml = simplexml_load_string($cdata);
```

**Step3** I have updated some node's values as follows.

```
    1. $cdata_as_xml->CusAccount['Action'] = 'Edit'
    2. $cdata_as_xml->CusAccount['DesiredCycleID'] = '1'
    3. $cdata_as_xml->CusAccount->AccountType->CusAccountType['AccountTypeID'] = '1000023'
```

**Step4** Now I need this updated XML to pass in another API as body as follows:

```
 $xml = '<CusAccount Action="Edit" AccountID="2046369" DesiredCycleID="1" Name="" 
             Corporation="" Cycle=""><AccountType><CusAccountType AccountTypeID="1000023" Version="1" 
             AccountTypeCode="BUS " AccountType="Business" MonthlyBillingMethod="P" /></AccountType> 
             <InvoiceFormat><ICInvoiceFormat InvoiceFormatID="1" UserID="10490655" 
             AddressAdjustmentY="0" AddressWidth="3500"/></InvoiceFormat></CusAccount>';
```

**But $cdata_as_xml something look like as follows:**

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
         [CusAccount] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
             ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Action] => Edit [AccountID] => 2046414 [DesiredCycleID] => 1 
                [Name] => [Corporation] => [Cycle] => ) 
                [AccountType] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                   ( [CusAccountType] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
                       [@attributes] => Array ( [AccountTypeID] => 1000023 [Version] => 1 
                         [ModifyDate] => 5/21/2009 9:46:00 AM [UserID] => 10120452 
                         [AccountTypeCode] => BUS [AccountType] => Business 
                         [MonthlyBillingMethod] => P 
                   ) 
              )
           ) 
           [InvoiceFormat] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
             ( [ICInvoiceFormat] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
                ( [@attributes] => Array ( [InvoiceFormatID] => 1 [UserID] => 10490655 
                    [AddressAdjustmentY] => 0 [AddressWidth] => 3500 ) 
                 )
              )
            )
          )
```

How can I get pure XML, not XML Object?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asXML()` to save XML into a file

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

If you don't specify a filename, the method will return a string, containing the well-formed XML of the Element.

Comment: Casting to string will give you the text content of an element, not the serialised XML that asXML() will give you.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Thank you for the quick reply. I have tried your solution and I can find the XML by `asXML()` method but how can I update an attribute value of node?
I have tried `$cdata_as_xml->CusAccount->Attributes->Action` return value is empty. But expected value would be "Edit".